# Javax.validation - how to validate a Date attribute with a specifies date

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have been trying validate a date attribute with *java.util.Date* class be means of *javax.validation* annotations.

I have found some annotation to do it, for instance: **@Past, @PastOrPresent, @Future, @FutureOrPresent**; however I need the validation will be with a specific date.

I am searching something like this:

```
@Future("01/01/2019")
```

Does someone know how can I do it?. I would like to do it with annotation existing (I don't like to do it with custom annotations).

Regards.

Comment: You can use Hibernate validation framework to create an annotation like @Future and you can validate.

Comment: ok, but of this way I should create a custom annotation right? or Does HIbernate's @Future annotation have attributes for doing that?

Comment: Hibernate validator framework provides simple way to create custom annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to create the annotation of this way:

**FutureCustom** annotation

Interface:

```
@Target({FIELD, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = FutureCustom.class)
public @interface FutureCustom {
    public abstract String max() default "";
    public abstract String message() default "Message";
    public abstract Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    public abstract Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Class:

```
public class FutureCustomImpl  implements ConstraintValidator<FutureCustom, Date> {

    private String max;

    @Override
    public void initialize(FutureCustom constraintAnnotation) {
        this.max = constraintAnnotation.max();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Date value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        //Validation using value and max like parameter in annotation
            // The max attribute will always be a String, you have to convert it to Date.
    }

}
```

Of this Way the annotation will be:

```
@FutureCustom(max="10/10/2010")
```